# Database ER Diagram

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relationship

Please explain to me the type of relationship portrayed using this flowchart:

[image]

Also, explain the different notation for a different type of relationship i.e
One-to-one, One-to-many, Many-to-one, Many-to-many. And what about the participation i.e Total or partial

Answer (score 0):

A record in table 1 maps to exactly 1 record in table 2. but a record in table 2 can map to 1 or many records in table 1.

for example if if table 1 is records of people, and table 2 is records of places of birth. each person in table 1 can only have one place of birth, but a place of birth can have many people